# grep can't get the word I need, but Linux continues to do the next job. How do I stop it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing, grep

I have quite a few txt files. They contain the word 'Minimum' (it only shows once in each file), and I want to get the line that contains this word, and show the line in a new file.
To do this, I use this command:

```
grep 'Minimum' file1.txt > new1.txt
```

I did this to each file (file1, file2, etc.), and got lots of `newn.txt`. But it turns out that some files don't have the word 'Minimum', so their `newn.txt` are empty. Well, if grep can't get the word, why doesn't Linux give me an error message? Why does it continue and make the newn.txt? Giving me some empty files is really annoying.
So is there a way that I can stop it from creating the `newn.txt` if it can't find the word?

Also, I'm thinking about putting it into a bash script - the grep command is the first step, and then in the second step I'll do something to the `newn.txt`. So if grep can't find the word, or if there's an empty file created, I want the script to stop and not to do the second step. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `grep` isn't going to give an error just because the pattern isn't found. It doesn't work in that way. If you have a script and you want it to stop after a certain condition then you need to add its contents to your question.

Comment: @NasirRiley The content of the second step or further steps is not the point. The point is that I want to tell Linux to stop from doing the second step if the first step is like that.

Comment: You asked why there isn't an error message when the pattern isn't matched and I told you why. The fact that it doesn't stop with an error when you want it to is irrelevant. As I said before, if you want your script to stop when the pattern isn't found then it is up to you to alter the code. It is not up to the operating system or the shell or the binary that you are using to do something that it isn't coded to do or to give an error message when there isn't an error. Add your script to you question and we can help you alter it to get the output that you want.

Comment: Actually, when you use the `>` redirection operator, creating (or opening, if it already exists) the file is the *first* step, done by the shell **before** executing the `grep` command

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah that's right. I've just realised that.

Answer (score 1):

The shell will create the output file before even running `grep`. The `grep` utility will then add contents to the file, if there is anything to add.  If `grep` does not find anything, the file will be left empty.

Another thing that happens if `grep` does not find anything matching in the input file is that it will exit with a non-zero exit status, signalling "failure".  This does not remove the output file, but you could act on the failure to remove the file like this:

```
grep 'PATTERN' infile >outfile || rm -f outfile
```

If `grep` fails to match `PATTERN` in `infile`, this would call `rm -f` to remove the empty `outfile`. Strictly speaking, this would also try to remove the file if `grep` failed for *any* reason (like e.g. not being able to read its input), or if the output file could not be created.

If you additionally want to terminate the script if no matches were found:

```
if ! grep 'PATTERN' infile >outfile; then
    rm -f outfile
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work here. I tried this command grep 'PATTERN' infile >outfile || rm -f outfile but it doesn't stop and still moves to the next step of my code. My next step is using awk to get a column from the outfile and then put it into a new file. Although grep didn't get the word in infile, awk still got an empty column and created an empty new file.

Comment: @LittleG You haven't shown us any part of your script other than the single `grep` command. We don't know what the rest of your code does or what it looks like. The only thing you said you had an issue with was the creation of the output file from the `grep` command. If you could edit your question to add a bit more code, then it would be easier for us to see what your code does and how it could be changed.  Also, using `awk` and `grep` together is seldom needed as `awk` can do everything `grep` can do and more.

Comment: Hiya, I said that in my question - my last sentence reads 'So if grep can't find the word, or if there's an empty file created, I want the script to stop and not to do the second step. Is there a way to do this?' I want it to stop and not start the second step.

Comment: @LittleG See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. What does the ! mean by the way? I've never seen any exclamation mark after the if

Comment: @LittleG `grep` returns an exit status which is either _true_ (success in finding the thing) or _false_ (failure to find anything). The `!` reverses the sense of this exit status, so that the body of the `if` statement is executed if `grep` did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop. Adjust it to your needs.

```
i=0
for file in *; do
    line=""
    line="$(grep -hm1 'Minimum' "${file}")"
    [ -z "$line" ] || echo "$line" > new"${i}".txt
    ((i++))
done
```

Change `*` in this line: `for file in *; do` to your file set.

Take care to weed out any unwanted grep output that might crop up.

Comment: The loop variable "file" appears to be unused within the loop's body, is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in file*; do grep -q Minimum "$i" && grep Minimum "$i" > "${i/file/new}"; done
```

- `grep -q Minimum "$i"` immediately exists after the first "Minimum" is found
- the second `grep` does the real job and is not executed if the first one fails
- `"${i/file/new}"` renames `file` in each filename to `new`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to prevent the script from continuing when a Linux command is *not successful* is by adding

```
set -e
```

to the start of the file. This will make any unsuccessful command stop the script. When `grep` does not find any matches, it will send and
unsuccessful signal. For example:

```
echo "starting"
echo "someword" > ex1.txt
cat ex1.txt | grep "otherword"
echo "continuing"
```

prints out

```
starting
continuing
```

But

```
set -e
echo "starting"
echo "someword" > ex1.txt
cat ex1.txt | grep "otherword"
echo "continuing"
```

prints out

```
starting
```